# hive RegexSerDe null

Tags: hive

How should I work with NULL values in RegexSerDe?
I have file with data:

```
cat MOS/ex1.txt

123,dwdjwhdjwh,456

543,\N,956
```

I have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE mos.stations (usaf string, wban STRING, name string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "input.regex" = "(.*),(.*),(.*)"
);
```

I successfully loaded the data from file to table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/hduser/MOS/ex1.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE mos.stations;
```

Simple select works fine:

```
hive> select * from mos.stations;

123dwdjwhdjwh456

543\N956
```

And next ends with error:

```
select * from mos.stations where wban is null;
[Hive Error]: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of possible issues:

1) It may not having anything to do with null handling at all. The first query doesn't actually spawn an M/R job while the second one does so it might be a simple classpath issue where RegexSerde is not being seen by the M/R tasks because its jar is not in the classpath of the tasktracker. You'll need to find where the hive-contrib jar on your system lives and then make hive aware of it via something like:

```
add jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib-0.7.1-cdh3u2.jar
```

Note, your path and jar name may be different. You can run the above through hive right before your query.

2) Another issue might be that the RegexSerde doesn't really deal with "\N" the same way as the default LazySimpleSerde. Judging by the output you are getting in the first query (where it returns a literal "\N") that could be the case. What happens if you query `where wban='\\N'`? or `where wban='\N'` (I forget if you need to double escape).

Finally, one word of caution about RegexSerde. While its really handy, its slow as molasses going uphill in January compared to the default serde. If the dataset is large and you plan to run a lot of queries against it, its best to pre-process so that you don't need the RegexSerde. Otherwise, your going to pay a penalty for every query. The same datset above looks like it would be fine with the default serde.